# CSS for colouring one row of an Ant Design table in React

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, antd

This is the CSS for the [Ant Design](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) style I'm using:

#### File *style.css*

```css
.ant-table-tbody > tr > td, .ant-table-thead > tr > th
{
    padding: 4px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #F1E6FF;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: white;
}

thead[class*="ant-table-thead"] th {
    background-color:#000 !important;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
  }

.table_btn
{
    margin:0 !important;
}

.ant-btn
{
    margin: 0;
}

.ant-table-tbody > tr:hover > td {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

#### File *index.less*

```
@import "callout";
@import 'e-commerce';
@import "pricing-tables";
@import "login";
@import "dashboard";
@import "error";
@import "editor";
@import "testimonials";


tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background:inherit !important;
}
.ant-modal-content {
    .ant-modal-close {
        color: #FFF !important;
    }
    .ant-modal-header {
        background-color: #000000;
        .ant-modal-title {
            color: #FFF !important;
        }
    }
}

.table-wrapper {
    .ant-btn {
        padding: 0 10px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 13px;
        > .anticon {
             + span {
                 margin-left: 5px;
             }
            }
        &.ant-btn-success {
            color: #3D8918;
            border-color: #D9D9D9;
            &:hover {
                background-color: #3D8918;
                color: #FFF;
            }
        }
        &.ant-btn-danger {
            color: #C70D17;
            background-color: #FFF;
            &:hover {
                background-color: #C70D17;
                color: #FFF;
            }
        }
    }
    .actions {
       text-align: right;
       .ant-input {
             border-radius: 2px;
             padding: 0 10px;
             font-size: 13px;
             height: 30px;
       }
    }
    .table-layout {
        .ant-table-small {
            > .ant-table-content {
                > .ant-table-body {
                    margin: 0 !important;
                    > table {
                        > .ant-table-tbody {
                            > tr {
                                > td {
                                    padding: 2px 8px !important;
                                    font-size: 13px !important;
                                    text-align: center;
                                    min-width: 80px;
                                    .ant-btn {
                                        width: 100px;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

#### File *index.js*

```
<Table
    className="table-layout"
    columns={this.state.columns}
    dataSource={filteredData}
    rowClassName='data-row'
    bordered={true}
    size={"small"}
    onRowDoubleClick={ (record, index, event) => this.handleEditModal(record) }
    onRowClick={(record, index, event) => this.handleRowClick(record)}
    loading={this.state.loading}
    pagination={{ pageSize: 14 }}
/>
```

This is how *Table* is used in the index page. Files *style.css* and *index.less* are the pages for CSS.

How can I write one CSS part on this page for making one row green color?

I want to make one row green based on condition.
I need the CSS.
I need to call the CSS in the page where the code is.

Comment: add an active class based on condition and add CSS`tr.active { background-color: green;}`

Answer (score 55):

I found two ways to do this as of now:

One way is to use the `rowClassName` prop of Table:

```css
.table-row-light {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.table-row-dark {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
}
```

```
<Table
  rowClassName={(record, index) => index % 2 === 0 ? 'table-row-light' :  'table-row-dark'}
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={dataSource}
  loading={loading}
/>
```

The second way is to use plain CSS:

```css
.table-striped-rows tr:nth-child(2n) td {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
}
.table-striped-rows thead {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```
<Table
  className="table-striped-rows"
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={dataSource}
  loading={loading}
/>
```

Note that rowClassName works only for rows, so for CSS on table headers, we can only use plain CSS like above.

Answer (score 11):

See if these [JSFiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFiddle) links help you. They show two ways to change *backgroung-color* of your rows.

[https://jsfiddle.net/2b2376a4/](https://jsfiddle.net/scs07x52/)

https://jsfiddle.net/2b2376a4/

```
data: [
          {id:1, name: 'one', color: '#fff'},
        {id:2, name: 'two', color: '#eee'},
        {id:3, name: 'three', color: '#ddd'}
      ]
```

For the first link:

```
  render(text, record) {
            return {
                props: {
                style: { background: record.color },
              },
                children: <div>{text}</div>,
            };
          },
```

For the second link:

```
 rowClassName={(record) => record.color.replace('#', '')}
```

Comment: How to disable `:hover` for the antd table?

Comment: Can we do this for headers as well?

Comment: @P-RAD 
I haven't tried that but I guess we can. You can also directly change the CSS by targeting .antd-table-head.

Comment: Please accept this answer so that the other developer knows the answer too.

Comment: Great! How did you get this?

Answer (score 4):

I am not a fan of using class names and I see nobody mentioned that there is another simpler approach by using the [`onRow` prop](https://ant.design/components/table#onrow-usage):

```
<Table
   ...
   onRow={(record, index) => ({
     style: {
         background: record === 'something' ? 'red' : 'default',
     }
   })}
/>
```

Comment: @MaximeLafarie I am glad it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use styled-components, you can wrap it like this:

```js
const StyledTable: React.FC<TableProps<T>> = styled(Table)`
  .ant-table-header th {
    background-color: green;
  }
`

export const Table = () => (
    <StyledTable
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={data}
      ...
    />
```